# Xubuntu 19.0.4 Unable to install any packages without reinstalling java installer

Tags: apt, xubuntu, java

I cannot install oracle-java12-installer due to being unable to accept the license agreement through the terminal. Furthermore, I am unable to install, remove, or purge **any** packages without reinstalling the oracle-java12-installer. It is as if oracle's Java has locked down dpkg.
How do I uninstall oracle's Java, and replace it with openJDK, given that I seemingly cannot use apt? I installed Java using the method outlined on the oracle site, then changed the oracle java to be the default java to use when I compile or run a java program.

Edits:

I cannot use any apt command to install, purge, remove, or update without a message being displayed in the terminal saying that it tried to reinstall oracle-java12-installer, but could not locate the archives. 
Because I cannot use any apt commands without reinstalling the java installer, and I cannot install the java installer due to being unable to accept the license agreements, I cannot add the repository that i *think* i need to update or install the oracle-java12-installer.

There is no button to click or anywhere to type to signify that I accept the java license agreement, so I am unable to reinstall the java12 installer.

How do I get control of apt back from the oracle-java12-installer?
I have successfully installed oracle's Java 12 by downloading the tar/gz file, and setting the contents to be the default whenerver I compile or run a java program.

Comment: "I cannot do X" is not helpful. What happens when you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove a oracle jdk that didn't install properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121226/how-to-completely-remove-a-oracle-jdk-that-didnt-install-properly)

Comment: @fkraiem There is no button to click on the license screen for oracle's java, and the keys that one would naturally press to accept or continue, like the enter key, do nothing.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `ls /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java12*` into your post Thank you for helping us help you! Did you by any chance try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/122012/225694) of course changing java7 to java12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer somewhere else, I think that I may have mistepresented my problem. 
[How to fix broken package manager - java oracle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952506/how-to-fix-broken-package-manager-java-oracle)